# What is Better for Mimicking PL/SQL Returning SQL in Interactive Reports: Collection or Pipelined-Function

Tags: report, oracle-apex, pipelined-function

The worst aspect of the Interactive Report (IR) is that you cannot create it using a PL/SQL returning SQL statement. I have gotten around this using two methods:

1) `APEX_COLLECTION.CREATE_COLLECTION` in the `Before Header Process`, which takes a SQL statement (that is constructed in PL/SQL in the process), and have the IR's source be `select c001 alias1, c002 alias2 ... from apex_collections a where collection_name = '...'`

2) Make a badass pipeline function with a parameter list as long as you need and then have the IR's source be `select * from table(package_name.pipelined_function_name(:P1_parameter1, :P1_Parameter2))`

Is there a performance difference? I originally used the first method but then ran into an occurrence where it was giving me a bug so I tried the pipelined function and found I just liked it better and have tended to use them ever since unless it was inappropriate to do so (namely when there is a large number of items to be passed to the parameter).

Comment: Hey Matthew, i also use the collection variant but i ran into an other problem. If i use the 1st method i can not make charts and calculations, because all cXXX(query returns more than 20 cols) are varchars. Is this behavior also included when i use the pipeline function ?

Comment: @Mario Nope, the pipelined function will return the correct datatype. First you can make a row, then a type table of those rows, and then the pipelined function returns a table of that type. Pipelined functions have been very helpful to me and I suggest you use them for this use case.

Answer (score 0):

First method gives you opportunity to cache data by re-creating the collection only when you need it. Using `n00X` and `d00X` columns will give you some additional performance and right column types for the report definition. You can also create a view based on that collection with type casting and column aliases to add more convenience:

```
create or replace view apx_my_report
  as
  select n001 id, c001 data, d001 some_date
    from apex_collections
   where collection_name = 'MY_REPORT'
/
```

In that case you report source will be like that:

```
select id, data, some_date from apx_my_report
/
```

On the other hand, when you need to execute an ad-hoc query every time when page is rendered, it leads to the unavoidable re-creation of a such collection, therefore the performance goes down because of unwanted transaction maintaining: undo, redo etc.

So, it depends.